# how to change simulator type?

Tags: ios, xcode, calabash

Whenever I'm opening my application by using start_test_server_in_background, i'm seeing my app in iPhone simulator. But I want to run in it on iPhone retina. Can anyone suggest me how to change the settings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more details. Please see this calabash-ios topic - http://goo.gl/yQi0bE - and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are running on Xcode 5.1.1

For more details see:  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/A0-Xcode-51-Support

```
$ DEVICE_TARGET="iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1" calabash-ios console`
> start_test_server_in_background`
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode menu bar:

```
Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...
```

Then at the top of the window change the `destination` to whatever device you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you run from XCode. you have to install more simulators in your XCode. First, check your XCode Preferences

[image]

Edit: It seems that your question is for Calabash for iOS. Take a look at this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/zZZcuvQOs_E

Comment: I'm running my application from console. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: This is information is not relevant to the question.